# Number of special ordered partitions of a 6-element set.

Tags: combinatorics

I am reading a book about convex polyhedra and I need help with combinatorics.

Let $S = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. I am interested in number $N$ of ordered partitions of $S$, such that there are $2$ singletons and $2$ sets with $2$ elements in a partition.

Examples of partitions I am interested in: $\{1, \{3,5\}, 6, \{2,4\}\}$ or $\{2, \{3,5\}, \{1,4\}, 6\}$.

Note that $\{1, \{3,5\}, 6, \{2,4\}\}$  and $\{1, \{5,3\}, 6, \{4,2\}\}$ are the same partitions. Also note that $\{ \{3,5\}, 1,6, \{2,4\}\}$ and $\{1, \{3,5\}, 6, \{2,4\}\}$ are different partitions because order is important.

How can I count them?

My naive approach via $N=\binom 6 2 \binom 4 2 \binom 2 1 4!$ turned out to be wrong, but I do not see why. I will appreciate/upvote if you explain me my mistake or tell me how to find $N$.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The reason it's wrong is it yields $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}, 5, 6\}$ 4 times, so you have to divide your formula by 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose which two elements are alone. There are ${6 \choose 2} = 15$ possibilities.

Of the remaining four elements $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$, choose the two sets to break it into. In particular, the partition is determined by which element goes with $a_1$, so there are $3$.

But now any ordering of what we have just chosen is unique, and we have not double counted since any other choice in step 1 and 2 yields a different partition! So in total we have $15 \cdot 3 \cdot 4! = 1080$.

Generally you can just find the number of partitions and then you can just multiply it by $k!$ where $k$ is the number of parts.

Answer (score 0):

First choose two 2-element and two 1-element sets, with no order. It is enough to just choose two 2-element sets, and you can do it in $\frac {1}{2}{6\choose 2}{4\choose 2} $ ways (the factor $\frac {1}{2} $ appears because, as I said, we ignore the order).

Now, when we account for possible orders, the number of partitions grows by factor $4! $ and so it is $\frac {4!}{2}{6\choose 2}{4\choose 2} $.